# Change color of negative/positive values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have added Matrix Visual in my PowerBi dashboard. I want to show all negative numbers as Red and positive numbers as green.

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional formatting feature of the Matrix Visual.
You can follow the example in the documentation:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-conditional-table-formatting/

Click on the dropdown of your "Values" field and select "Conditional Formatting". Then you can select the "Diverging" checkbox. Then in the "Center" select "Number" and enter a cero value in the box underneath. This will allow you to assign the green color to number above cero and red to numbers below cero.

Comment: If you just enter zero in the middle box of the color scale (e.g. red-yellow-green), it can give yellow color to negative numbers. To create a (nearly) fixed color scheme, you can give manual values to all colors, e.g. 0 for red, 1 for yellow and 2 for green. This will give the same red for all negatives, and the same green for every value above 2.